How to achieve JSON serialization with inheritance in Dart using json_serializable?
I'm working with Dart and the json_serializable package to manage JSON serialization for my models, and I have encountered an issue regarding inheritance.
I have the following base model:
@JsonSerializable()
class BaseLeadModel {
  final String? name;
  final String? email;
  final String? contactNo;

  BaseLeadModel({this.name, this.email, this.contactNo});

  factory BaseLeadModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$BaseLeadModelFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$BaseLeadModelToJson(this);
}


And I have a derived model that extends BaseLeadModel:
@JsonSerializable()
class AddLeadModel extends BaseLeadModel {
  final String? leadStatusId;
  final CreateLeadEnquiryModel? enquiry;

  AddLeadModel({
    this.leadStatusId,
    this.enquiry,
  }) : super();

  factory AddLeadModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AddLeadModelFromJson(json);
  
  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AddLeadModelToJson(this);
}


The Problem:
When I generate the serialization code using flutter pub run build_runner build, the generated fromJson and toJson methods for AddLeadModel do not include the fields from BaseLeadModel. This leads to issues where the base class fields are not serialized or deserialized properly.
How can I ensure that the fields from the BaseLeadModel are included in the serialization and deserialization processes for the AddLeadModel class?

Is there a way to automatically include inherited fields in the generated JSON serialization code?
If I have to manually implement fromJson and toJson methods, how can I do that while still leveraging inheritance effectively?

i have tried the following way
AddLeadModel({ String? name, String? email, String? contactNo, this.leadStatusId, this.enquiry, }) : super(name: name, email: email, contactNo: contactNo);
But my base model may have more nummber of properties, and i not want to repeate again and add the same properties in my base model.

While you could write
  AddLeadModel({
    String? name,
    String? email,
    String? contactNo,
    this.leadStatusId,
    this.enquiry,}) : super(
      name: name,
      email: email,
      contactNo: contactNo);

You can shorten it by writing this instead
  AddLeadModel({
    super.name,
    super.email,
    super.contactNo,
    this.leadStatusId,
    this.enquiry,});

As far as I know there's no way to leave out the super's parameter.

so I need to add all the base class properties in its child constructor too? then I think keeping the child with all properties will be good. ?

You have to spell it out in the constructor.  The constructor signature must contain all the properties you want set.
